# Reading an EXCEL file from bucket into Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload this data into from my bucket into bigquery, but it's complaining.
My file is an excel file.

```
ID          A   B   C          D             E      F           Value1  Value2
333344      ALG A   RETAIL     OTHER         YIPP   Jun 2019    123     4
34563       ALG A   NON-RETAIL OTHER         TATS   Mar 2019    124     0
7777777777  -   E   RETAIL     NASAL         KHPO   Jul 2020    1,448   0
7777777777  -   E   RETAIL     SEVERE ASTHMA PZIFER Oct 2019    1,493   162
```

From python I call the file as follow:

```py
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()
    
    table_id = "project.dataset.my_table"
    
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
       bigquery.SchemaField('ID','STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('A','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('B','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('C','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('D','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('E','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('F','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Value1','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Value2','STRING'),
    
        ],
        skip_leading_rows=1
        )
    
    uri = "gs://bucket/folder/file.xlsx"
    
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.
    
    load_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
    
    table = client.get_table(table_id)
    print("Loaded {} rows to table {}".format(table.num_rows, table_id))
```

I am getting the following error, and its complaining about a line that it's not even there.

```
BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 8, but line starting at position:660 contains only 1 columns.
```

I thought the problem was the data type, as I had selected ID as integer and value1 and value2 as Integer too and F as timestamp, so now I'm trying everything as String, and I still get the error.

My file is only 4 lines in this test I'm doing

Comment: It will be easier to convert it to CSV indeed. Doing so, make sure the numbers do not contain the comma separating thousands, millions, etc. It will mess up your formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Excel files are not supported by BigQuery.

A few workaround solutions:

- Upload a CSV version of your file into your bucket (a simple `bq load` command will do, cf [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load)),
- Read the Excel file with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel) in your python script and insert the rows in BQ with the [to_gbq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html)() function,
- Upload your Excel file in your Google Drive, make a spreadsheet version out of it and [make an external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets) linked to that spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `field_delimiter` in the `LoadJobConfig`

Comment: Doesnt work, I keep getting the same error. The file is in excel, does it have to be csv?

Answer (score 0):

Your input file seems like TSV.
So you need to set field delimiter to `'\t'` like this,

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
  schema=[
    bigquery.SchemaField('ID','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('A','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('B','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('C','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('D','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('E','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('F','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Value1','STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Value2','STRING'),
  ],
  skip_leading_rows=1,
  field_delimiter='\t'
)
```

Comment: Doesnt work, I also saved the file as a csv file, but now the error says a different line: BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 8, but line starting at position:33 contains only 1 columns.